# I was hired for one job profile, then assigned to another job profile which I don't want to continue with

Tags: communication, software-development, internal-transfer

I was hired for a job profile the company needed and one that I love. But on joining, the passed me on to another type of job, which I had not learned before and had no plans of learning in the near future.

Nonetheless, I started to work on the other job as I thought it is a good opportunity to learn something new. But now I am getting permanently migrated to this profile. I can develop skills but I do not want to.

How should I tell them about the real problem, without getting into any trouble?

Finally I have tried the direct approach to my direct manager and will get their decision soon as we were facing performance issue.

Edit: I told them I got another better job opportunity as they are not able to keep their keep up their word

Edit: I told my manager, HR and even Higher that I will not continue if they will force me on that profile. They told my I won't be assigned that task any longer but they got another project and again assigned me and therefore I ended up on new job.

**Thank you all for suggestions that prevented fraud like situation**

Comment: Hello and welcome to Workplace.SE. Unfortunately, this question is off-topic as we can't help you choose what job to take.

Comment: @michael I just want to ask that is it good to tell HR directly about this concern?? or I should move on (Best possible advice??)

Comment: @user7036414 We can not make your life decisions for you. Only you have the first-hand knowledge and personal connection to estimate if the problem is solvable, if the situation is bearable or if you need to look for another job. But we might be able to help you when you rewrite the question to ask about *how to tell HR about your concern*.

Comment: @Philipp please read the question again, I have made a edit, Please tell me if need to edit more??

Comment: @user7036414 I edited the question some more to remove superfluous parts and most of all the off-topic "should I reconsider my job?" part which we can not answer and nominated the question for reopening.

Comment: With @Philipp's good edit, this question is no longer "what should I do?" Voted to reopen with some more minor edits to the question.

Comment: What is a "job profile"? That doesn't make sense to me. Do you just mean a job?

Comment: @MikeHarris In a sense yes. I no longer will be doing what I was hired for but new job with different skills or no skills

Comment: @MikeHarris For all practical purposes, you could think of "job profile" as a synonym for "job description". That term is used in some locales.

Comment: @MaskedMan I can edit that, and that will remove confusion

Comment: @user7036414 No, it is fine. It is clear enough from the context, and that was the terminology that the OP (which is you, in this case) used in the question.

Comment: I am sorry, I made it already

Comment: Is it a different job, or did the job description just change or was not what you were expecting? Are you prepared to quit the job if they are not flexible (e.g. "We need someone to do this job")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My take is that if you were hired to do X, but you are then to do Y. The key word here is hired. You have a choice of continuing to do Y for $ or say "no thanks".

You are always free to give your preferences and inform your manager of your unhappiness, but at the same time, know that the needs of the organization will supersede your personal preferences when it comes to decision-time.

As for what you can say,

> Hello Boss, I know I was hired for X, but for the last few [time period] I was tasked with Y. Although it was out of my comfort zone, I think I've learned quickly and done a good job. I was wondering if it would be possible for me to be tasked with X now that Y is done.

Frame it as a win-win for both you and the organization, rather than complaining.

Comment: I told them, they promised me win win situation but this time brought 2 new projects and sadly I ended up on new job in new company which is even better in terms of commitment and with more salary.

Comment: Not sad. But good for you then. Do well and prosper!

Answer (score 6):

You need to discuss this with your manager. This could be a case that they needed someone like you for that position until you can move to something you are interested in.
If this is a company you love you can stay, prove yourself and move to a better role. If you believe you will be pigeonholed to that role for good then you need to vocalize your concern strongly and leave if you are ignored. It's up to you actually. You only know how much you need this job and if you have to stay or not. So it is not real trouble to speak out on your needs. But you will have to make a choice in the end

Comment: I have decided to leave the company and already had conversation with my HR and manager too

Answer (score 1):

This is an important career move, review your options very carefully before you do anything at all as you could find yourself replaced by someone willing to do the work rather than moved to work you want. So factors to consider range from how easy you are to replace versus how much experience and value you have to the company. My take is you don't have a lot of leverage, but you'd know your situation best.

Your options are basically:-

Speak to your manager, this is probably not going to work since he/she would have been part of the decision behind your change of work. But your manager is always your first recourse. Escalate if you must and think it's worth the risk.

Put up with doing the work while you at least job hunt for something more suitable.

Quit or threaten to do so by complaining a lot or refusing to do the work. Whenever a person complains there is always a percieved implicit threat of further action if their complaint is not dealt with to their satisfaction.

Comment: "Complaining a lot" could be understood as "whine constantly to co-workers and clients". This is unprofessional and immature. Don't do this. "Refusing to do the work" while continuing to accept your salary is fraud. Don't do this.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri yes, refusing is not a good option to take, doesn't stop people from taking it though and in some scenarios it is fine. But you extrapolated my intended meaning of 'complaining'; to something different.

Comment: The reall problem is that I have some experience and I am working in startup... and the profile I am being migrated to .. I will start as fresher.
Now.. The point is all of my experience is waste

Comment: I told my manager that I will not continue if they will force me on that profile. They told my I won't be assigned that task any longer but they got another project and again assigned me and therefore I ended up on new job

Answer (score 1):

Some markets are too small to wear only one hat, and even so much less in small firms.

The problem may stem from communication problems, lack of skill managements from your superiors, or both.

Hiring time is normally the time to ask questions and clarify what the organization expects.

Ultimately, if you are not happy, it may be time to move on and start looking for a new position. I pretty much doubt they can enterely accomodate for your wishes in a small/startup environment..

Comment: They still have the project I was hired for. They assigned me other task on higher priority now wants me to work on that profile which I told them is not a good idea and waiting for their response

Comment: You have to work on your own to distinguish wether that will be a permanent thing. e.g. they may not be interested in explaining things to you, quite by the contrary, they might string you along as long as you allow them to